# $\int_{\cup_i A_i} X \;d\mu =\sum_i \int_{A_i} X \,d\mu$ for $X$ integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space, $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R} $ integrable and $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ ($I$ countable indexset) pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathcal{F}$. Does then $$\int_{\cup_i A_i} X \;d\mu =\sum_i \int_{A_i} X \,d\mu$$ holds?

Normally this follows from the monotone convergence theorem. But since $X$ is not non-negative we can't use it here. Is it instead possible to argue with the dominated convergence theorem?

Attempt: Let $i_1, i_2, \dots$ be a numbering of the elements of I. Define $f_n:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}X\;\mathbb{1}_{A_{i_j}}$. Then $f_n(\omega)$ converges to $f(\omega):=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X \; \mathbb{1}_{A_{i_j}}(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. Since $f,f_n$ are measurable and $|f_n|\leq |X|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{A_{i_j}}\leq |X|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $|X|\in \mathcal{L}^1,$ all conditions of the dominated convergence theorem are given. It follows that $$\int_{\cup_i A_i} X \;d\mu = \int \mathbb{1}_{\cup_i A_i} \; X\; d\mu=\int \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_{i_j}} \;X \,d\mu=\int f_  \,d\mu=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \; d\mu=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int \mathbb{1}_{A_{i_j}}\; X \;d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{A_{i_j}} X \;d\mu$$

Comment: Good!$\mbox{ }$

Comment: @UmbertoP. ok, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Conventionally, "$\cup$" is used for things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and "$\bigcup$" for things like $\bigcup_i A_i. \qquad$